# VHDL: DELAY_LENGTH vs. $NATURAL_TIME

Tags: vhdl

While searching for some references in the VHDL `STANDARD` package, I saw these lines:

```
subtype $NATURAL_TIME is TIME range 0 sec to TIME'HIGH;
subtype DELAY_LENGTH  is TIME range 0 fs  to TIME'HIGH;
```

**My question:**
Why is
- `$NATURAL_TIME` ranging from `0 sec` and
- `DELAY_LENGTH` ranging from `0 fs`
to the upper bound of time?

Source: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/standard.vhdl

Comment: `$NATURAL_TIME` is not a valid VHDL identifier nor is it found in Package STANDARD.  `DELAY_LENGTH` is  and has a TIME value range from 0 to TIME'HIGH.  `0 sec` and `0 fs` represent the same TIME value, units are used as multipliers. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.2.4.1 para 9 "The position number of the value corresponding to a physical literal with an abstract literal part is the largest integer that is not greater than the product of the value of the abstract literal and the position number of the accompanying unit name."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file has this header:

```
-- The sven STANDARD package.
-- This design unit contains some special tokens, which are only
-- recognized by the analyzer when it is in special "bootstrap" mode.
```

Clearly the tool using this file has made some alterations to suit their particular implementation. Presumably it had issues with `DELAY_LENGTH` when the minimum time step is larger than `1 fs` so a special subtype type was created.

Comment: An abstract literal part of `0` is exempt from the **5.2.4.2 Predefined physical types** rule on the appearance of a secondary unit smaller than the *resolution limit*. A TIME value of `0` always means `0` no matter the secondary unit. See **5.2.4.1** paragraph 9.  The range of the special token and `DELAY_LENGTH` subtypes are identical and neither depends on a secondary unit. The comment preceding the special token `-- subtype used internally for checking time expressions for non-negativness:`. It has nothing to do with `DELAY_LENGTH` which is the type returned by impure function `NOW`.